# How to have driver.refresh at different interval from time.sleep of a while loop?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Not-coder me trying to code, experts please bear with my questions. 
I tried to search around but couldn't find a solution.

Question:
Is it possible to have a while loop with time.sleep, but driver.refresh of different interval time?

"Do something" will loop every 10 seconds but driver.refresh will only reload page every 5 mins.

```
while True:
    [Do something....]
    time.sleep(10)
driver.refresh() <<--(How to make drive.refresh at different interval from time.sleep?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution.

```
timer = 0
while True:
    [Do something....]
    timer += 1
    if timer > 10
        driver.refresh()
        timer = 0
    time.sleep(10)
```